# Switched from Federated Login back to Google Accounts API - Nothing but Errors

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

In preparation for the depreciation of Federated Logins, I moved my users over to my own login system - no problems there.

However I was hoping to continue to use the Users API to continue to login as an admin so I could access parts of the application that are admin only as specified by the app.yaml

In the dashboard I have changed the Authentication Type to Google Accounts API but when I browse to the login url below I get A server error.

```
https://triton.ironhelmet.com/_ah/login?continue=https://triton.ironhelmet.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the appengine logs report?

Comment: no error in the log,

Comment: I assume the error is that it is still trying to do a Federated Login, and instead of giving some meaningful error message, it's just crashing.